# no matching provisioning profiles found tvOS

Tags: xcode, matching, provisioning-profile, tvos

I have an tvOS application that give me a *"no matching provisioning profiles found in xcode 7"*, I have created a tvOS Distribution profile, downloaded it, doubleclicked. But I then get that message, and try to use the *"Fix issue"* button does not help. In Build settings - Provisioning Profile - I have *"Automatic*".
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find an answer here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/21704

*You'd need to do the following:
(1) Generate a distribution signing identity using the Team Details sheet in Xcode's Preferences > Accounts pane
(2) Generate a tvOS App Store profile on the Member Center, download it, and install it into Xcode by double clicking the downloaded profile
(3) In your target's build settings, change the signing identity to "iOS Distribution" for release builds, and change your provisioning profile setting to the name of the profile they downloaded for release builds.*